# I want to spin wind turbine but its not rotating from center of the turbine pole

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to rotate turbine in `360 degree` but Its not rotating from its center. Whole turbine is rotating in 360 degree. I want it to spin from its initial position. [Js bin link](https://jsbin.com/rotaworuge/1/edit?html,css,output)

```css
#main-blade {
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
  /*  transform-origin: center; */
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 87.77 110.21"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#46b800;}</style></defs>
<g id="turbine" data-name="Layer 2">
  <g id="blade" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="main-blade">
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="48.6 39.8 55.43 36.21 86.51 41.19 87.77 46.15 48.34 43.14 48.6 39.8"/>
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="32.19 46.4 29.9 53.77 4.39 72.22 0 69.62 30.01 43.86 32.19 46.4"/>
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="32.22 34.33 25.11 31.32 9.27 4.12 12.3 0 34.96 32.41 32.22 34.33"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M45.53,41.62a6.24,6.24,0,1,1-6.24-6.24A6.23,6.23,0,0,1,45.53,41.62Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M45.08,39.31c0,.1,0,.2,0,.3A6.81,6.81,0,0,1,34,44.89a6.23,6.23,0,0,0,11.54-3.27A6.1,6.1,0,0,0,45.08,39.31Z"/>
    </g>
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.01 49.98 46.44 110.21 33.97 110.21 37.01 50.59 44.01 49.98"/>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of using the `transofrm-origin` is correct. But when you would draw a bounding box around your `#main-blades`, you could see that see that the center of the bounding box is not equals the center of the turbine. This means you have to identify the correct origin for the transformation by calculate the correct `%`-values or you simply do it by try and error and accept it when you're a little bit off :)

```css
#main-blade {
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
  
  transform-origin: 44.8% 37.8%;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 87.77 110.21"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#46b800;}</style></defs>
<g id="turbine" data-name="Layer 2">
  <g id="blade" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="main-blade">
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="48.6 39.8 55.43 36.21 86.51 41.19 87.77 46.15 48.34 43.14 48.6 39.8"/>
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="32.19 46.4 29.9 53.77 4.39 72.22 0 69.62 30.01 43.86 32.19 46.4"/>
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="32.22 34.33 25.11 31.32 9.27 4.12 12.3 0 34.96 32.41 32.22 34.33"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M45.53,41.62a6.24,6.24,0,1,1-6.24-6.24A6.23,6.23,0,0,1,45.53,41.62Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M45.08,39.31c0,.1,0,.2,0,.3A6.81,6.81,0,0,1,34,44.89a6.23,6.23,0,0,0,11.54-3.27A6.1,6.1,0,0,0,45.08,39.31Z"/>
    </g>
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.01 49.98 46.44 110.21 33.97 110.21 37.01 50.59 44.01 49.98"/>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I found those values (`44.8% 37.8%`) by keeping a static version of the image and rotate it 180deg. This simulates the moment where the distance between the origin and the rotated image is the largest.

So the css would look like this:

```
#main-blade{
  transform-origin: 44.8% 37.8%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**Edit**: *Calculate the real x-origin of the blades*

Let's find as example the x-offset of the origin of the main blades in below's schema. The schema represents the initial position of the main blades in your svg. Find the given distances with the tool of your choice. The unit is not important, but must be the same for all measures.

The **red point** represents the center of the image.
The **green point** the origin of your main blades.

[image: calculation on paper]

You can see that the center of the image is at `4.4cm`. Then it's just to find out the offset in percents. So, `4.4cm / 8.7cm = 1/2 => 50%`<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huQVu.png)</sup>.
Now let's find out the x-offset of the real origin of the blades: `3.8 cm / 8.7cm` = 0.4367 = 43.57%`.

---

<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huQVu.png)</sup>: Should be 4.35 instead of 4.4. Sorry for the imprecision... OpenOffice Draw doesn't show values smaller than 1mm....

Comment: thanks for the answer and is there any debugging steps to identify the correct origin for the transformation??

Comment: @sanjeevshrestha Check the edit. I tried to visualize a possible approach. Regards, Uchendu

Comment: @uchendu-Thankyou for your efforts :)